# Running a Docker Image on Local Folder

Tags: python, linux, docker

I need to use a docker image which has compiled versions of certain programs that are very hard to compile from scratch.

I need to run a program in that environment.

I installed docker and pulled the image.

But how do I run a program (A Python program that works in the docker environment) using the environment provided to me by docker, sending in the local folder as input and producing the output back to my local system.

So far all resources tutorials show me how to work inside docker and not the problem I want.

Thanks for our help.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at bind mounts. Here’s the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) of those.

Essentially, that will mount a folder in the host as a folder in the container.

Comment: It’s on the documentation page.